# scroll to before page load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make the page load 200px further down using javascript. But I always see 1 second of the top before is scrolls down.

vimoe does this, try scrolling up after the page is loaded, http://vimeo.com/49645156

margin-top:-200px.. Gives me this effect, but I cant' scroll up after margin is set with a negative number.

Maybe make a jquery solution that changes the body margin-top after the page is loaded, will that work?

Currently using this script

```
function jumpScroll() {
window.scroll(0,200); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets

}
```

I just call this script from the body with onload.

Comment: I think you'll find that actually the content you scroll up to on vimeo is loaded just after page load, and the scroll position is set at that point. The content isn't loaded as part of the initial markup, if you see what I mean, it is loaded via jQuery or some other framework.

Comment: If you look in the page source, you will see `<div id="brozar" class="hide"><h3 class="loading">Loading videos&hellip;</h3></div>`. Class `hide` sets it to `display: none` and then the content is loaded after the page is rendered. Hope this helps.

Comment: And you can't actually see the 'loading' bit because their servers are very, very fast. All their JS is minified, but if you search it, you can find the function that's asynchronously loading content into the `#brozar` div and scrolling the page on completion.

Comment: So if I put a div with top: -200 .. and then append a html with query? Will that work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving margins, why don't use the division id?

I am sure you have given a ID to the division which you want to show on top when loading.

just use the div ID, like this :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var div= $('#example'); // take your div id
    $(window).scrollTop(div.offset().top).scrollLeft(div.offset().left);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work.. I have a div that i've put all content into.. Trying to use $("#container").scrollTop(200); .. but doesnt work.

Comment: so you have made your complete website in a single division ? :\

Comment: well.. one way to use scrollTop. I could use body or document instead of div.. But it doesn't seem to have good enough browser support. Works ok in safari.

Comment: It's strange, it works in safari through jsfiddle, but when i copy the source code that's in the result window it stops working.

Comment: Make sure you're on the same version of jQuery, and if it still doesn't work then make sure either the js is at the end of the body or, preferably, that it is in the head within `$(document).ready(function() { //do your stuff here });`. If it still doesn't work then please post the code you have in the question.

Comment: Thanks for answering ClarkeyBoy! I copied exactly the code from fiddle. Try this in safari and chrome. Works in chrome, not safari. http://dagensoutfit.co/scrolltop/ ..exactly the same code.

Comment: Well guys, I think I have to continue the search for a different solution. scrolltop still starts at the top before scrolling down, this is probably because other content have to be loaded before the scripts executes. Everything above the site has to be loaded afterwards somehow. Big thanks for your help, i'm getting closer :)

Comment: Got it - `#Brozar` is loaded at the end of a `div` called `#main`, and then it is prepended to the body. If you look in the source, you will see that it starts of after the main content (you can also see this if you disable JS). It is then prepended to the body which has the scrollbar at which point I assume they set the scrolltop on the body. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also note that the jsFiddle works in both Chrome & Safari, so there *must* be some difference. Try viewing the source of the red frame - you can see exactly what it is doing there, including the `$(window).load` function wrapping the jQuery entered in the JS frame.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done in such a way:
1. Load empty div with content of height you need for all the pages.

2.Perform scroll to the required content. As it will be the first thing that was done on page load, before even content loaded it would be invisible.

3.Load the actual content via ajax or with templating.

Comment: well you would see the scrollbar jump, even if you don't see the rest of the page move...

Comment: Scroll jump on vimeo as well.

Comment: yeah thanks, checked it out now. I myself didn't even notice, so you're right, it doesn't matter xD