# How to automatically scroll the window to some height as the page loads

Tags: jquery

I want to automatically scroll the page to 120px as the page loads please help.

I am new to Javascript and jQuery so please use easy javascript or jQuery (And P.S. I'm familier with the "function" thing in javascript).

THANX.

Comment: What have you tried already? These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-with-jquery?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761971/scroll-to-before-page-load?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/fRUUd/1511/)

Code `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);`

Answer (score 6):

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: 120 }, "slow");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1508/)

Make sure that,You write the above line in `document.ready()` function

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript approach

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1509/) by [sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927832/ss)

```
document.body.scrollTop = 1000;
```

Comment: +1 for the pure javascript line.Here is the fiddle ---->http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1509/

Answer (score 1):

If you are scrolling to a particular element with id `element-id`, you can use this:

```
document.getElementById("element-id").scrollIntoView();
```